# Prevent pandas from rounding integers when creating dataframe from lists

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, rounding

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(listoflists, columns =['size', 'text'])
```

I converted a `listoflists` to a two column pandas `df1`

```
listoflists = [[10.5, 'qqqqq \t\n'], [11.0, 'rrrreee \n'], [10.5, 'rrrrr \n'], [10.000000000000057, 'ertttt \n'], [7.500000000000007, 'ert: ert \n']]
```

The col `size` is automatically rounded. How can i prevent pandas from doing this? I want to retain all decimals.

```
print(df1)

              size                                               text
0             10.5                                         qqqqq \t\n
1             11.0                                         rrrreee \n
2             10.5                                           rrrrr \n
3             10.0                                          ertttt \n
4             7.5                                         ert: ert \n
```

I tried

```
df1.style.format({
    'size': '{:,.3f}'.format})
```

but that doesent help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data is stored correctly. In order to view it with your preferred precision, use this command after importing pandas:

```
pd.set_option("display.precision", 15)
```

Set the number of precision digits to as many as you need.